# Usage of "would" for future

Tags: grammar

Where can we use "would" for future without conditional sentences? Please describe with example of sentences.

Answer (score 7):

What you are referring to is the subjunctive mode/mood.

If you are a mathematician, and understand the conjugal relationship between real and imaginary numbers, you would see that the subjunctive is the imaginary conjugate of the real world.

The imaginary/subjunctive realm has the same set of tense structure mirroring the real tenses.

Therefore, the subjunctive/imaginary realm also has past, present and future tenses, as well as progressing and perfected states.

To speak of the imaginary realm, even about the imaginary future, we borrow the past tense of the real world, because the imaginary realm does not have its own set of terminology for tenses.

What makes a situation imaginary? Examples are ...

- Impossibility: I would be a bird and I would sing all day.
- Proposal: If you came to my house, I would feed you all day.
- Conditional: If you come to my house, I would feed you all day.
- Condescension: Could you take your shoes off?
- Uncertainty: The bridge would probably fall by next year. It is so old.

In many cases, condescension is the reason for future subjunctive.

> Would you take your shoes off before you come into my house tomorrow? It is going to be a snow storm day, with 6 inches of snow.

Condescension mood is a form of politeness frequently used by native speakers of English to implicitly say, "I know taking your shoes off is an impossible request I am making. It would make me very happy if you would do it."

Rather than saying in a less polite manner

> Will you take your shoes off before you come into my house tomorrow?

Examples of sentences made about the imaginary realm, that are not conditional situations

1. You would be dead by tomorrow, when the [skitters and their mechs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XsZIJ4spm2c) comb this area.
2. The price of gold would fall by this time next year.
3. I would use her advice, to survive your attack on the alien base next week.
4. You should not come back, after you have destroyed the alien base.
5. Would you take a bath and clean up, tomorrow?

*#3* is an implied conditional. "I would put on a bra (if I were you)." It is frequently used by a teacher on students, where the teacher forces herself onto the shoes of the student, to tell what the student should do. It is not a conditional to the main story of the sentence, but an auxiliary conditional. Therefore, it should still qualify to the non-conditional constraint you specified.

Comment: https://fallingskies.fandom.com/wiki/Skitters, 
https://fallingskies.fandom.com/wiki/Mechs

Answer (score 5):

**Would**

> "Would" is most commonly used to create conditional verb forms. It also serves as the past form of the modal verb "will." Additionally, "would" can indicate repetition in the past

**would "conditional"**

> If he were an actor, he would be in adventure movies.

**would
past of "will"**

> I knew that she would be very successful in her career.

**would
"repetition in past"**

> When they first met, they would always have picnics on the beach.

**"Future in the Past"**

> Like Simple Future, Future in the Past has two different forms in English: "would" and "was going to." Although the two forms can sometimes be used interchangeably, they often express two different meanings.

FORM Would

[would + VERB]

Examples:

> I knew you would help him.
>
> I already told Mark that when he arrived, we would go out for dinner.
>
> I knew John would finish the work by 5:00 PM.

[WOULD references](http://www.englishpage.com/modals/would.html)

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a sentence such as "I would have to convince her to talk to me". Here, the sentence uses would for the future. Also imagine unreal situations, in which something hasn't happened and its possibility is in question. "I would love to talk to Catherine." In this case, the talking hasn't happened, and it is unlikely to happen, and also even if it ever happens, it will entirely be in the future.

What Geolopez said: Not correct. The sentence should be "If she said yes, I would draft the contract right away."

Always, when it comes to second conditional, use the first part in past simple, even if it occurs in the future. For instance:

If it rained tomorrow, I would still go to college.

Here, rained is in the future, remember!

So, to answer your question, use would for any unreal future situation. Also to denote future actions of the past, such as:

I told my girlfriend yesterday that I would work out for two hours.

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetical/Conditional future. Consider the following sentence:

> If she said yes, I would draft the contract right away.

In this case, would was use to indicate that drafting the contract will be done only after a certain condition is met.

EDITED:

As it was pointed out in a comment below, the above example is a conditional statement.

However, would can also be used as a past tense of will.It also conveys actions which were usually done in the past.

> During the times he was with her, he would play the piano for her.

Comment: I think that's still a conditional.

Comment: oops, pardon. Sorry